# Together with the message, all information about all messages is displayed

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, form-with

I do chat on action cable. And I have a problem with post view. However, in order to show a message from a user, it additionally outputs the entire hash of all messages in this chat.
This what i get:
[chan with extra json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APq70.png)

When i use developer tools in chrome i saw it block without any selector or style. I can delete it in tools but can't remove it in view.
My post controller:

```
    def index
     @posts = Post.all
    end

    def show
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.customer = current_customer
      @post.save
    redirect_to request.referrer

     SendMessageJob.perform_later(@post)
    end
```

rooms index.html.haml

```
    #room-id{"data-room-id" => @room.try(:id)}
     #customer-id{"data-customer-id" => current_customer.id}
      .container-fluid
       .row
        .col-3.rooms-sidebar
          %b Создать новое объявление
           = render 'form', room: Room.new
           %hr
           - @rooms.each do |room|
            .room-link
              = link_to room do
               .card.mb-2.room-card
                 .card-body
                   %span.name
                    = room.name
                    = link_to 'Delete', room, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 
                                                             'Are you sure?' }
   .col-9
     - if @room.present?
       .chat-room
         = @room.name
         = image_tag @room.image.url(:thumb), class: 'img-show' if @room.image?
         #messages
           = @room.posts.each do |post|
             = render 'posts/post', post: post
        .chat-box
          = render 'posts/form', post: Post.new, room: @room
```

my db schema

```
      create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.string "image"
        t.string "content"
      end

      create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.text "title"
        t.text "content"
        t.bigint "customer_id", null: false
        t.bigint "room_id", null: false
        t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_posts_on_customer_id"
        t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_posts_on_room_id"
      end
```

posts/_form.html.haml

```
    = form_with(model: post, local: true) do |f|
     - if @post && @post.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2= "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from 
             being saved:"
         %ul
          - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            %li= message
     .field
       = f.hidden_field :room_id, value: room.id

     .input-group
        = f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Type your message...', class: 
          'form-control', style: 'width: 100%'

      .actions
        = f.submit 'Send message', class: 'btn btn-primary', style: 'width: 100%'
```

I don't understand where the extra json comes from below and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `= @room.posts.each do |post|` to `- @room.posts.each do |post|`. The json result comes from the `each`.